Planner and Power Automate Challenge
I have premium MS365 account but don't have any access to azure.
In Planner, when a plan is being copied/duplicated. The new copy plan will drop all the assignees that was assigned to the tasks. So I have made a power automate(PA) flow that is manually triggered and updates all the tasks to the assignees. However, its not automated. So, I want to make a flow using PA that is triggered automatically every time when a plan is being copied/duplicated (not task in existing plan but a duplicate of an existing plan). So far I have tried two approaches and both dont really work.

Approach 1: Make a flow with the PA built in methods/trigger. BUT With the given PA Planner triggers, all triggers asks for specific preexisting plan id so I have to enter the ids every time I run the flow. Making it not Automated.

Approach 2: I can make a scheduled flow and use the HTTP method and special conditions to check if the new plan has been added then check if it has same tasks as other plans. So, if two tasks are same the new one can be categorised as a copy. BUT Since I dont have Azure, I cant really get the token for the HTTP method to pull the API.


Overall, I wanted to have a fully automated system whenever I copy the plan in Planner, it creates a exact same duplicate with all the assignees in it. I cant really think of other approaches and asking if anyone has any ideas about such challenge. Any idea is welcomed!
